# NullPointerException when dealing with SharedPreferences within OnClick

Tags: android, if-statement, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm experimenting with `SharedPreferences`, but I've been having some difficulties with it.

In my Activity I need to call my `SharedPreferences` when a `Button` is clicked and the solution is correct. Not only does the check for whether my solution is correct not work, the app crashes with a `NullPointerException` whenever I call my `SharedPreferences`. Any Tips?

Here's my Activity:

```
package com.mitonanetherlands.buttonchooser;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class LevelFour_1 extends Activity {

        MoPubView ad1,ad2;
        TextView Level;

        public static int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
        public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

            // Calculate inSampleSize
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        }

    ImageView person1,person2,person3,person4,person5,person6;
    ImageView slot1,slot2,slot3,slot4,slot5,slot6;
    ImageView Appartementen;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level_sjabloon);
        Level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SjabloonText);
        Level.setText("Level 4-1");

        ad1 = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.LevelLeftTop);
        ad2 = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.LevelRightTop);
        ad1.setAdUnitId("4f53c030c3e211e295fa123138070049");
        ad2.setAdUnitId("1abf4e6ac3e311e295fa123138070049");
        ad1.loadAd();
        ad2.loadAd();

        person1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Person1);
        person2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Person2);
        person3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Person3);
        person4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Person4);
        person5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Person5);
        person6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Person6);

        slot1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Slot1);
        slot2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Slot2);
        slot3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Slot3);
        slot4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Slot4);
        slot5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Slot5);
        slot6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Slot6);

        Appartementen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.AppartementenComplex);

        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
        Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Reset);

        person1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        person2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        person3.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        person4.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        person5.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
        person6.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

        slot1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        slot2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        slot3.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        slot4.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        slot5.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        slot6.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());

        person1.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bea,300,450));
        person2.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.eline,300,450));
        person3.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.guido,300,450));
        person4.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pierre,300,450));
        //person5.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.rosalinda,300,450));
        //person6.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.wong,300,450));
        person1.setTag(R.drawable.bea);
        person2.setTag(R.drawable.eline);
        person3.setTag(R.drawable.guido);
        person4.setTag(R.drawable.pierre);
        //person5.setTag(R.drawable.rosalinda);
        //person6.setTag(R.drawable.wong);


        Appartementen.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.huisje,300,450));

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(slot1.getTag().toString()) == R.drawable.guido && slot2.getTag() == null &&
                    Integer.parseInt(slot3.getTag().toString()) == R.drawable.bea && Integer.parseInt(slot4.getTag().toString()) == R.drawable.eline &&
                           slot5.getTag() == null && Integer.parseInt(slot6.getTag().toString()) == R.drawable.pierre){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your solution is correct! Unlocking next level...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SharedPreferences completedLevels = LevelFour_1.this.getSharedPreferences("com.mitonanetherlands.buttonchooser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = completedLevels.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("Level 4-1", true).apply();
                            editor.putString("Last Completed", "4-1").apply();
                            startActivity(new Intent("com.mitonanetherlands.buttonchooser.L4_2"));
        //  }else{
                if(person1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person3.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){    
                    person3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person4.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person5.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person6.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                        person6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};
                    slot1.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot1.setTag(null);
                    slot2.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot2.setTag(null);
                    slot3.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot3.setTag(null);
                    slot4.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot4.setTag(null);
                    slot5.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot5.setTag(null);
                    slot6.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot6.setTag(null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong! Resetting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //  }
                }
        }});

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(person1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person3.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){    
                    person3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person4.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person5.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                    person5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    };if(person6.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                        person6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};
                    slot1.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot1.setTag(null);
                    slot2.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot2.setTag(null);
                    slot3.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot3.setTag(null);
                    slot4.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot4.setTag(null);
                    slot5.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot5.setTag(null);
                    slot6.setImageBitmap(null);
                    slot6.setTag(null);
            }
        });

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                /*
                 * Drag details: we only need default behavior
                 * - clip data could be set to pass data as part of drag
                 * - shadow can be tailored
                 */
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                //start dragging the item touched
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } 

    private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
                //no action necessary
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //view dragged item is being dropped on
                ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;
                //view being dragged and dropped
                ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;
                 int plaatje = (Integer) view.getTag();

                Object tag = dropTarget.getTag();
                //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
                if(tag!=null)
                {
                    //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                    int existingID = (Integer)tag;
                    //set the original view visible again
                    findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                //set the tag in the target view being dropped on - to the ID of the view being dropped
                dropTarget.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),plaatje,100,150));
                dropTarget.setTag(dropped.getId());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //no action necessary
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ad1.destroy();
        ad2.destroy();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ad1.destroy();
        ad2.destroy();
    }



}
```

Here's the LogCat:

```
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at com.mitonanetherlands.buttonchooser.LevelFour_1$1.onClick(LevelFour_1.java:144)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
05-27 13:47:03.974: E/AndroidRuntime(17912):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what line is the 144th? Still slot1.getTag().toString()), I can not see where do you call setTag on slot1, for instance

Comment: Line 144 is 
´if(Integer.parseInt(slot1.getTag().toString()) == R.drawable.guido && slot2.getTag() == null &&´
but I'm guessing that the rest of the if-statement counts as well.

Comment: still I can not see where do you initialize the tag ? you do it inside the layout?

Comment: It's a drag and drop interface, when you drag a person inside a slot, the tag is set to its drawable (R.drawable.(the person you drop)), and within the if-statement, it is retrieved. I do not set tags within the layout, that's done dynamically

Comment: still is better to check if the returned values is != null

Comment: I think I solved it, at line 272 i set the tag of the dropTarget to dropped.getId(), which should have been getTag(). It works now

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a value which you have not yet set. Before using `getTag()` you should set some valid `Object` reference as Tag for `slot1`.
You can set a tag to slot1 wherever you are instantiating it.

This is the reson why you are getting `NullPointerException` in `onClick()` (line 144) while getting the tag value from slot1. Moreover, I see that you are setting `null` as a tag for slot1 in line no. 167:

```
slot1.setTag(null);
```

which again will result in `NullPointerException` while getting the Tag for slot1 if a proper Tag is not set before that.

***Solution:***
You **must** pass a valid `Object` reference whenever using `setTag()` for any `View`. More info **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)**.

Comment: But that tag is only set when the solution is not correct, when I click, the tag is not yet set to null, but it fails before that

Comment: Alright, that again is a problem. You are trying to use some value which you have not set. It'll return null in that case too. I've modified my answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

need to commit that editor

```
editor.putString("Last Completed", "4-1");
editor.commit();
```